# AWS Lambda python function output remains "Hello from Lambda" even after changing the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I just started learning AWS Lambda today and tried to create a simple Hello World function in Python. The sample code which AWS generates looks like this:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Running this code gives the following output:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

But now when I try to modify this code and run it I get the exact same output as the sample code. I modified it to this:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello!')
    }
```

But I still get this as output:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

Things I've tried:

1. Deleting the function and creating a new one.
2. Using a different test event.

Neither worked. I also watched videos on YouTube where people are doing exactly what I was and their code change seemed to work.
Can someone please help me with what I am missing?

Comment: How do you run your script? Looks to me like you accidentally run an older script (file).

Comment: are you editing the code in the AWS Console directly?  how are you running/testing the function?

Comment: I run my script by clicking "Test" directly from the console. I am making changes to the sample script and not creating a new file. So I am not sure how the old version of script may get executed. And yes, I'm editing the code directly in the AWS console.

Comment: @Utkarsh, note that besides pressing `CTRL` `S` in the consule, you also has a `Save` box at the top of the editor which really deploys the Lambda.

Comment: It finally worked. Changes to the code only reflected when I click on "Deploy" first and then "Test".

Answer (score 14):

Clicking on "Deploy" first and then "Test" worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I am unable to leave comments yet as I don't have 50 reputation but I wanted to give the solution that worked for me in order to help others.